# Symfony 2 : getReference and find

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using the entity manager `getReference()` or `find()` method returns a non initialized object for some records of the database. Do you know why and what should be done?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: The `getReference()` or `find()` methods of Doctrine returns a boolean `false` value if the record is not found. Are you sure the record exists in the database? Can you show your attempts at the code?

Comment: I'm guessing that non-initialized for find means that not all of the objects associations are filled in?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`getReference()` does not load the object if it has not been loaded yet, it only returns a proxy to the object.

`find()` returns a loaded object.

cfr. [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork.html):

```
// this call does not trigger a db query, but creates an empty proxy with the ID
$objectA = $this->entityManager->getReference('EntityName', 1);

$this->assertInstanceOf('Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy', $objectA); // === true

// this will trigger a query, loading the state that's configured to eager load
// since the UnitOfWork already has a proxy, that proxy will be reused
$objectB = $this->entityManager->find('EntityName', 1);

$this->assertSame($objectA, $objectB); // === true
```

`getReference()` exists for special use cases, if you are fetching objects to use them, always use `find()`.